# How can I show that the pgf of the sum of n independent discrete random variables is equal to the product of their probability generating functions?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

How could I show that if $S = X_1 + X_2 +...+ X_n$ then
$E(z^{S}) = E(z^{X_1})E(z^{X_2})...E(z^{X_n})$

Where E is the expectation.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: With or without knowing that the expectation of a product of independent rv is the product of the expectations?

Comment: Oh I think without knowing as I just wanted to be able to show that the question statement is true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables.  Then
\begin{align}
E(z^{X + Y}) &= \sum\limits_{k =0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X+Y = k)z^k\\
&= \sum\limits_{k =0}^\infty \sum\limits_{r = 0}^k \mathbb{P}(X = r \wedge Y = k-r)z^k \\
&= \sum\limits_{k =0}^\infty \sum\limits_{r = 0}^k \mathbb{P}(X = r)\mathbb{P}(Y = k-r)z^rz^{k -r} \\
&= \left(\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X= k)z^k\right) \left(\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(Y= k)z^k\right) \\
&= E(z^X) E(z^Y)
 \end{align}

Now use induction on $n$.